# Print page using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a `DIV` in my HTML file with `WIDTH: 2500px`. That div carries **horizontal flow** of flow chart done with `POSITION:ABSOLUTE`. When i give browser print, it shrinks and reduces **font size**. But it shouldn't shrink and shouldn't reduce font-size as well. Please give me suggestions on this or give me some work-around.

Thanks,
Dinesh

Answer (score 0):

[Media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html) are key.

```
@media print{
    body{
        font-size:16px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

`font-size in %(percent like 100% or 80%)`While using the percent unit, your text remains fully scalable for mobile devices and for accessibility.

or Use Media Queries

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 320px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:<size>px/em/cm;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-device-width : 1024px)
{
  body or yourdiv element
  {
    font:<size>px/em/cm;
  }
}
```